# Primefaces p:ajaxStatus for non ajax requests

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I have some requests that can't be ajax requests, is there any way to still use the p:ajaxStatus component with non-ajax requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Non-ajax requests completely reload the whole page. So you can't literally use `p:ajaxStatus` to indicate that a non-ajax request being in progress.

If your request results in page navigation, then there is no use of `p:ajaxStatus`. Otherwise you could couple up the ajax request with `p:ajaxStatus`.

Shortly p:ajaxStatus can not be used to show the status of non ajax request.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit late, but I did basically what you're talking about.  The goal was to display the animated gif on non-ajax requests  I used this function to turn on the ajaxStatus display.  My p:ajaxStatus has an id of "ajaxStatus":

```
function startAjaxStatus() { 
  document.getElementById("ajaxStatus_start").style.display='block'; 
  document.getElementById("ajaxStatus_complete").style.display='none'; 
  document.getElementById("ajaxStatus_error").style.display='none'; 
  document.getElementById("ajaxStatus_default").style.display='none'; 
}
```

Now you just need to make sure you call that function before the non-ajax request:

```
<p:commandButton ajax="false" onclick="startAjaxStatus()" ...
```